# Understanding memory mapping

Tags: memory, assembly, x86, virtual, paging

In a modern PC, where will

```
MOV [0x0000], 7
```

put a 7? Is it the first byte of my RAM, or is it the first byte of the process's address space? Assuming it triggers a memory violation.

Comment: if it triggers a memory violation then how can it put the value into that address?

Comment: You mean assuming it *doesn't* trigger an access violation?

Comment: Is it in protected mode?  What OS is running, or are you in real mode with your own boot sector??

Answer (score 1):

You mean assuming it *doesn't* trigger an access violation?  Every process has it's own [virtual address space](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Virtual_memory).  The first 64kiB are normally kept unmapped, so NULL-pointer accesses actually fault noisily, instead of letting programs silently do Bad Things.

In a user-space process on a typical OS, an absolute address of `0` does refer to the first byte of your process's virtual address space.

With paging enabled, there's no way even for the kernel to use physical addresses directly.  To write to a given physical address, would have to create a page table entry mapping that physical page to a virtual page (or find an existing mapping), `invlpg` to make sure the TLB isn't caching a stale entry, and then use that virtual address.

Answer (score 0):

it depends on the system architecture. Every architecture provides an instruction set and a memory layout. Furthermore it depends on the operating system you use. E.g. Real Time Operating systems often do not provide Virtual Memory.

greets

Comment: What are my windows 8.1 / Ubuntu Linux more likely to be using? What are the results of running the above MOV in these OS?

Comment: OS like Win or Linux are using virtual address space meaning that it is not really the physical address. 
The Instruction above looks like a machine instruction that manipulate the CPU's register set.

https://support.amd.com/TechDocs/24594.pdf (page 217)